# Who is the manufacturer of this DIP and is there any datasheet or documentation for it? Top marking FD633D 1230

Tags: identification, dip

Here is the DIP I have:

[image: photo of DIP device]

FD633D 1230

I've tried to search for it and the only good result I get is this for sale at E-Bay and AliExpress and the page has no details regarding it. I tried contacting the seller but they don't have any datasheet.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit 1: It was from a Chinese seller so it might be a Chinese manufacturer. Also this same thing was being sold by several other sellers with different brand names, but same logo on the chip.

Comment: If you can't get any information on it, why do you want it? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Resembles "Signetics" logo. Now which mega-company consumed them many years ago?

Comment: Ron Beyer, It was used with a 7 Segment display and some push buttons so I think it might be a controller. I just want to see what it is and so maybe I can find a use.

Comment: @glen_geek maybe the signetics logo with bits shaved off it, but I cant find any of their ICs on google that dont have the full logo, even the small ones

Comment: No bits shaved off, its the complete logo.

Comment: When I search Google for FD633D, the first image that comes is a [picture](https://img.techpowerup.org/200626/ZDY2NWQ0ODcyYjIx.jpg) a chip like this, and the batch is 1230 too - the same batch than the IC in your photo. (this chip was for selling in AliExpress but the add is not active now) **By the way, the picture that you posted seems that have been partially edited.** The epoxy seems to be high-res photo, but the pins are somewhat pixelated.  Do you really have this chip with you?

Comment: Mguima, to get a high res picture of this I scanned this in a scanner and then enhanced too make it look clear. I also found those results and contacted the seller but they were unable to give me any info. useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's made by [Fuda Hisi Microelectronic](http://www.fdhisi.com/)s in Fuzhou, China. A CMOS LED and key scan device.

```
Introduction: FD633 is a special LED driver control circuit with keyboard scanning circuit interface. Internally integrated MCU input and output control digital interface, data latch, LED driver, keyboard scanning, brightness adjustment and other circuits. The chip has stable performance, reliable quality and strong anti-interference ability, and can be adapted to the application occasions of long-term continuous work for 24 hours.
 • Adopt power CMOS process
 • Display mode: 7-segment×5 digits, or 8-segment×4 digits
 • Key scan: 7×1
 • Brightness adjustment circuit (duty cycle 8-level adjustable)
 • Three-wire string Line interface (CLK, STB, DI/O)
 • Oscillation mode: built-in RC oscillation (frequency is 450KHz±5%)
 • built-in encryption function
 • power supply: support 3V-5.5V power supply voltage, typical value 3.3V
 • Adopt DIP18, SOP20 package
```

I don't see a working datasheet link.

Comment: Love you! How did you even find this tho?

Comment: This one was easy- the last character is usually a package code, so try searching without it. The 1230 is probably a date code (manufactured in the 30th week of 2012).

Comment: I found this page with the same information than @Spehro: [https://img.techpowerup.org/200626/fd633.jpg](https://img.techpowerup.org/200626/fd633.jpg) The original page is in Chinese, this is the translation by Google Chrome. A Google search returns datasheets for FD620, FD650, both seem to be similar to FD633 (control of 7-segment displays). But the datasheets are in Chinese.